# Change text background on canvas using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js object to change the text background color on canvas
following is my code it's working but not in proper way what i exactly want.
Following is the out put of this code when i run it.
[image: enter out put of my code]

```
$("#textbackground").click(function() {
//  alert("textbackground");
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
 if (!obj) return;
 obj.setTextBackgroundColor('rgb(0,200,0)');
 canvas.renderAll();
 });
```

I have to apply the background to text following like this

[image]

Comment: set line height to be the same as the size of your font?

Comment: please explain in brief...

Comment: If the issue is that the green background area is taller than the text, this could be the issue (making the area around the text the same height as the text so the background doesn't bleed too high or too low, to explain it poorly). If the issue is that you would like your text on an angle, you would be best of with a CSS3 transform, I think.

Comment: @SanjayNakate What exactly do you want?

Comment: @Kienz Just i have to apply green background color according to the text height just like in 2nd image i have attached, not to the whole text like in the 1st image.

Comment: You need to use `fabric.Text` and set the background color on that. That image is from this tutorial: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/ Why don't you use the code right above the image you've shown here?

Comment: fabric.Text not working @SergiuParaschiv

Comment: You have to be more specific. What's not working? I've used it ten times the last two weeks and it works as expected.

Comment: Will you please elaborate the code (fabric.Text) as you mentioned in your first comment @SergiuParaschiv

Comment: Well, turns out `lineHeight` works, but text background is stretched to full height. Never noticed this as that was what I needed. I tried this with all major releases and there's no way I can reproduce the results in that image. Maybe it depends on the font used. http://jsfiddle.net/eaZzX/

Comment: Fine @SergiuParaschiv